# Blackjack casino game

Tags: python, game, playing-cards

> Blackjack (twenty-one) is a casino game played with cards. The goal of
>   the game to draw cards that total as close to 21 points as possible
>   without going over. All face cards count as 10 points, aces count as 1
>   or 11, and all other cards count their numeric value.
>
> The game is played against a dealer. The player tries to get closer to
>   21 (without going over) than the dealer. If the dealer busts (goes
>   over 21) the player automatically wins (provided the player had not
>   already busted). The dealer must always take cards according to a
>   fixed set of rules. The dealer takes cards until he or she achieves a
>   total of at least 17. If the dealer's hand contains an ace, it will be
>   counted as 11 when that results in a total between 17 and 21
>   inclusive; otherwise, the ace is counted as 1.
>
> Write a program that simulates multiple games of blackjack and
>   estimates the probability that the dealer will bust. Hints: treat the
>   deck of cards as infinite. You do not need to keep track of the cards
>   in the hand, just the total so far (treating an ace as 1) and a bool
>   variable hasace that tells whether or not the hand contains an ace. A
>   hand containing an ace should have 10 points added to the total
>   exactly when doing so would produce a stopping total(something between
>   17 and 21 inclusive).

It runs, but I'm just looking to improve it if possible.

```
def printIntro():
    print("This program simulates a bunch of blackjack games.")

def getInputs():
    while True:
        n = eval(input("How many games should be simulated? "))
        if n <= 0:
            print("You must enter a number greater than zero!")
        else:
            break

    return n

def simOneGame():
    score = 0
    blacklist = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
    while not gameOver(score):
        blackscore = blacklist[randrange(len(blacklist))]
        score = score + blackscore

        if score >= 17: 
             break
        if blackscore == 11 and (score >= 6 and score <= 10): 
            score = score + 11
        else:
            score = score + 1

    return score

def simNGames(n):
    holds = 0
    busts = 0
    for i in range(n):
        score = simOneGame()
        if score >= 22:
            busts = busts + 1
        else:
            holds = holds + 1

    return holds, busts

def gameOver(score):
    return score >= 22 or score >= 17

def printSummary(holds, busts):
    n = holds + busts
    print("Number of holds and busts: Holds: {0:0} Busts: {1:0}".format(holds, busts))
    print("Percentage of holds and busts: Holds: {0:0.1%}".format(holds / n), end = " ")
    print("Busts: {0:0.1%}".format(busts / n))

def main():
    printIntro()
    n = getInputs()
    score = simOneGame()
    holds, busts = simNGames(n)
    printSummary(holds, busts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def printIntro():
    print("This program simulates a bunch of blackjack games.")
```

Python style guide recommend lowercase_with_underscores for function names

```
def getInputs():
    while True:
        n = eval(input("How many games should be simulated? "))
```

not a really good idea to use eval, because that allows the user to input any python expression which may not make sense. Instead use int, which will only allow numbers

```
        if n <= 0:
            print("You must enter a number greater than zero!")
        else:
            break

    return n

def simOneGame():
    score = 0
    blacklist = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
    while not gameOver(score):
        blackscore = blacklist[randrange(len(blacklist))]
```

Python has a function, random.choice() which returns a random element from a list.

```
        score = score + blackscore

        if score >= 17: 
             break
```

Why? The loop will terminate anyways. There doesn't seem to be a reason to break here

```
        if blackscore == 11 and (score >= 6 and score <= 10): 
            score = score + 11
        else:
            score = score + 1
```

I assume that this has to do with handling aces, but I don't understand the logic. You've already added blackscore to score, so I wouldn't think this would do the right thing. Also, couldn't you need to change the value of an ace to a 1, from an eleven due to later cards?

```
    return score
```

You only really care about busts/holds so maybe you should return True or False?

```
def simNGames(n):
    holds = 0
    busts = 0
    for i in range(n):
        score = simOneGame()
        if score >= 22:
            busts = busts + 1
        else:
            holds = holds + 1

    return holds, busts

def gameOver(score):
    return score >= 22 or score >= 17
```

That's the same as score >= 17, no reason to include the first part of the condition

```
def printSummary(holds, busts):
    n = holds + busts
    print("Number of holds and busts: Holds: {0:0} Busts: {1:0}".format(holds, busts))
    print("Percentage of holds and busts: Holds: {0:0.1%}".format(holds / n), end = " ")
    print("Busts: {0:0.1%}".format(busts / n))

def main():
    printIntro()
    n = getInputs()
    score = simOneGame()
    holds, busts = simNGames(n)
    printSummary(holds, busts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't import the `randrange` function from the `random` module. Without this, it won't work.

Comment: It's quite likely they just didn't copy imports into the question, assuming that it wasn't necessary.